# Amazon Transcribe streaming with Node.js using websocket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, streaming, amazon-transcribe

I am working on a whatsapp chatbot where I receive audio file(ogg format) file url  from Whatsapp and I get buffer and upload that file on S3(sample.ogg) Now what is want to use AWS Transcribe Streaming so I am creating readStream of file and sending to AWS transcribe I am using websocket but I am receiving Empty response of Sometimes when I Mhm mm mm response. Please can anyone tell what wrong I am doing in my code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto'); // tot sign our pre-signed URL
const v4  = require('./aws-signature-v4'); // to generate our pre-signed URL
const marshaller  = require("@aws-sdk/eventstream-marshaller"); // for converting binary event stream messages to and from JSON
const util_utf8_node = require("@aws-sdk/util-utf8-node");
var WebSocket = require('ws') //for opening a web socket
// our converter between binary event streams messages and JSON
const eventStreamMarshaller = new marshaller.EventStreamMarshaller(util_utf8_node.toUtf8, util_utf8_node.fromUtf8);

   // our global variables for managing state
   let languageCode;
   let region = 'ap-south-1';
   let sampleRate;
   let inputSampleRate;
   let transcription = "";
   let socket;
   let micStream;
   let socketError = false;
   let transcribeException = false;
  // let languageCode = 'en-us'

app.listen(8081, (error, data) => {
    if(!error) {
        console.log(`running at 8080----->>>>`)
    }
})

let handleEventStreamMessage = function (messageJson) {
    let results = messageJson.Transcript.Results;

    if (results.length > 0) {
        if (results[0].Alternatives.length > 0) {
            let transcript = results[0].Alternatives[0].Transcript;

            // fix encoding for accented characters
            transcript = decodeURIComponent(escape(transcript));

         console.log(`Transcpted is----->>${transcript}`)
        }
    }
}

function downsampleBuffer (buffer, inputSampleRate = 44100, outputSampleRate = 16000){
    if (outputSampleRate === inputSampleRate) {
        return buffer;
    }

    var sampleRateRatio = inputSampleRate / outputSampleRate;
    var newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
    var result = new Float32Array(newLength);
    var offsetResult = 0;
    var offsetBuffer = 0;

    while (offsetResult < result.length) {

        var nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);

        var accum = 0,
        count = 0;

        for (var i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++ ) {
            accum += buffer[i];
            count++;
        }

        result[offsetResult] = accum / count;
        offsetResult++;
        offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;

    }

    return result;
}


function pcmEncode(input) {
    var offset = 0;
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(input.length * 2);
    var view = new DataView(buffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 2) {
        var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
        view.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
    }
    return buffer;
}

function getAudioEventMessage(buffer) {
    // wrap the audio data in a JSON envelope
    return {
        headers: {
            ':message-type': {
                type: 'string',
                value: 'event'
            },
            ':event-type': {
                type: 'string',
                value: 'AudioEvent'
            }
        },
        body: buffer
    };
}


function convertAudioToBinaryMessage(raw) {

    if (raw == null)
        return;

    // downsample and convert the raw audio bytes to PCM
    let downsampledBuffer = downsampleBuffer(raw, inputSampleRate);
    let pcmEncodedBuffer =  pcmEncode(downsampledBuffer);
    setTimeout(function() {}, 1);
    // add the right JSON headers and structure to the message
    let audioEventMessage = getAudioEventMessage(Buffer.from(pcmEncodedBuffer));

    //convert the JSON object + headers into a binary event stream message
    let binary = eventStreamMarshaller.marshall(audioEventMessage);

    return binary;
}

function createPresignedUrl() {
    let endpoint = "transcribestreaming." + "us-east-1" + ".amazonaws.com:8443";

    // get a preauthenticated URL that we can use to establish our WebSocket
    return v4.createPresignedURL(
        'GET',
        endpoint,
        '/stream-transcription-websocket',
        'transcribe',
        crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'), {
            'key': <AWS_KEY>,
            'secret': <AWS_SECRET_KEY>,
            'protocol': 'wss',
            'expires': 15,
            'region': 'us-east-1',
            'query': "language-code=" + 'en-US' + "&media-encoding=pcm&sample-rate=" + 8000
        }
    );
}

function showError(message) {
    console.log("Error: ",message)
 }


app.get('/convert', (req, res) => {
        var file = 'recorded.mp3'
        const eventStreamMarshaller = new marshaller.EventStreamMarshaller(util_utf8_node.toUtf8, util_utf8_node.fromUtf8);
        let url = createPresignedUrl();
        let socket = new WebSocket(url);
        socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
        let output = '';
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, { highWaterMark: 32 * 256 })
        readStream.setEncoding('binary')
        //let sampleRate = 0;
        let inputSampleRate = 44100
        readStream.on('end', function() {
            console.log('finished reading----->>>>');
            // write to file here.
             // Send an empty frame so that Transcribe initiates a closure of the WebSocket after submitting all transcripts
                  let emptyMessage = getAudioEventMessage(Buffer.from(new Buffer([])));
                  let emptyBuffer = eventStreamMarshaller.marshall(emptyMessage);
                  socket.send(emptyBuffer);
          })

    // when we get audio data from the mic, send it to the WebSocket if possible
      socket.onopen = function() {
        readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
         let binary = convertAudioToBinaryMessage(chunk);
         if (socket.readyState === socket.OPEN) {
             console.log(`sending to steaming API------->>>>`)
             socket.send(binary);
         }     
        });
            // the audio stream is raw audio bytes. Transcribe expects PCM with additional metadata, encoded as binary
        }
                // the audio stream is raw audio bytes. Transcribe expects PCM with additional metadata, encoded as binary


        socket.onerror = function () {
            socketError = true;
            showError('WebSocket connection error. Try again.');

        };

          // handle inbound messages from Amazon Transcribe
    socket.onmessage = function (message) {
        //convert the binary event stream message to JSON
        let messageWrapper = eventStreamMarshaller.unmarshall(Buffer(message.data));
        //console.log(`messag -->>${JSON.stringify(messageWrapper)}`)
        let messageBody = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(String, messageWrapper.body));
        console.log("results:.. ",JSON.stringify(messageBody))
        if (messageWrapper.headers[":message-type"].value === "event") {
            handleEventStreamMessage(messageBody);
        }
        else {
            transcribeException = true;
            showError(messageBody.Message);

    }
  }

  let closeSocket = function () {
    if (socket.OPEN) {

        // Send an empty frame so that Transcribe initiates a closure of the WebSocket after submitting all transcripts
        let emptyMessage = getAudioEventMessage(Buffer.from(new Buffer([])));
        let emptyBuffer = eventStreamMarshaller.marshall(emptyMessage);
        socket.send(emptyBuffer);
    }
}


})
```

Comment: Please can anyone help me to resolve this problem. It's really urgent for me. Because I can't find any document for readStream from audio file